# Parameters Collapsable fields on SSRS report work in browser but not in webforms report viewer

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, user-interaction, ssrs-2019

Using SSRS 2019
.net 4.6
Webforms reportviewer 15

I have a report with parameters and collapsable rows, to allow drilling down to specific items.  This works fine in Visual studio and via the web. When I try to embed the report using the webforms report viewer, changing the parameters doesn't work and the clicking on the plus symbol doesn't expand.  It looks like all interaction with the report fails.

Any advice greatfully received.

Comment: WinForms or WebForms? Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the developers here found me the solution.  Two settings needed to be updated.

- myreportviewer.InteractivityPostBackMode = 1
- MyReportViewer.AsyncRendering = False